# How to slice a list (or create sublists) based on elements in original list that differ by a set value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my first time asking a question here, so please don't roast me too much as I try to get the swing of things.

I am working on some code using Python 3. So, in my code I generate a list. For the sake of specificity, suppose I am working with the following list:

```
a = [3344, 3354, 3364, 3364, 3374, 3374, 3384, 3384, 3394, 3394, 3404, 3404, 3414, 3414, 3424, 3434]
```

I would like to sort this list into the following sublists:

```
sub1 = [3344, 3354, 3364, 3374]
sub2 = [3364, 3374, 3384, 3394]
sub3 = [3384, 3394, 3404, 3414]
sub4 = [3404, 3414, 3424, 3434]
```

So, I would like to sort the original list into sublists based on the elements that differ by a known value, in this case 10.

I am unable to use index-based slicing and have not yet been able to implement any kind of lambda function to accomplish this. I have searched through the depths of Stack Overflow and have not found anything particularly helpful.

Thank you for the help.

Update:

I wanted to add some more information to clear up any confusion resulting from lack of specificity in my language. The goal is to generate sublists with four elements from the original list, with the elements of the sublist differing by a value of 10.

To better explain what I am trying to accomplish here, I will provide a second list and the desired output sublists.

```
b = [3384, 3404, 3344, 3394, 3374, 3414, 3354, 3404, 3384, 3424, 3364, 3414, 3394, 3364, 3434, 3374]
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
sublist1 = [3344, 3354, 3364, 3374]
sublist2 = [3364, 3374, 3384, 3394]
sublist3 = [3384, 3394, 3404, 3414]
sublist4 = [3404, 3414, 3424, 3434]
```

I need to be able to generate this output, as these sublists will be used as input values for different functions later on... Capturing the degenerate values is a must.

I hope this clears things up!

Comment: Is the given list `a` always sorted, and all elements differ by the known value (10)?

Comment: The list a is sorted here. The structure prior to the sort is random, meaning the elements will not always appear at a certain index. The elements will always differ by the known value.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want here. Do you want all sets of 4 numbers in a row (separated by 10s) that can be constructed from the input list? If so, why don't you want the sublists `[3354, 3364, 3374, 3384]` or `[3374, 3384, 3394, 3404]`? Also, will the inputs always use +10 spacing (e.g., ending in 4 like here)? And will there ever be gaps that are larger than 10? (i.e., are you just trying to filter out duplicates or also work around gaps?)

Comment: I'm sorry it is not clear. Basically, I am trying to group four related line positions (represented by the four elements of a given sublist) together. Each sublist represents a group of these related line positions. In this given example, we have four groups. The first value in the sorted list (call it x) will always be the first value of the first sublist, which must have four elements that are evenly spaced, in this example by 10. The first sublist will then be [x, x+10, x+20, x+30]. The spacing between elements in the sublist will always be a set number, which can be any number from 1-50.

Comment: I apologize for the additional comment, but there is a character limit. I am trying to work around gaps. I chose the gap to be 10 for the sake of simplicity, but I think I have inadvertently made it more complicated. The first duplicated element in the original list will always be the first element of sublist2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `for` loop that appends an item in `a` to an existing sublist whose length is less than 4 and whose last item is 10 less than the item, or otherwise create a new sublist with the item:

```
l = []
for i in a:
    for s in l:
        if len(l) < 4 and s[-1] + 10 == i:
            s.append(i)
            break
    else:
        l.append([i])
```

Given your sample input, `l` would become:

```
[
    [3344, 3354, 3364, 3374],
    [3364, 3374, 3384, 3394],
    [3384, 3394, 3404, 3414],
    [3404, 3414, 3424, 3434]
]
```

Note that your expected output is incorrect because the items in your input `a` can be sorted into two sublists without breaking the rule of all adjacent items differing by 10.

Comment: All of the logic in your code is spot on, however, I am trying to generate the expected output... So based on the initial list, I am trying to generate the four sublists. The criteria that jumped out at me was that there is a difference of ten. I suppose the output listed above would be more accurately referred to as the "desired output". My apologies!

Comment: So you need to define your rule more clearly that would result in the expected output. Otherwise there's no defined reason to break up the two sublists further.

Comment: My apologies! I am still working on learning the vernacular so I can effectively communicate exactly what I am trying to accomplish to real programmers... I'm not exactly sure how to better or more clearly define my rule, because my rule is a "function" of the output... I am trying to come up with a rule that will allow me to generate the desired sublists given the initial list.

Comment: I've updated my answer with your new requirement of a maximum length of a sublist being 4.

Comment: I went ahead and tested out your code. When I run it, I am getting the following output for l:

    l = [[3344, 3354, 3364, 3374, 3384, 3394, 3404, 3414, 3424, 3434], [3364, 3374, 3384, 3394, 3404, 3414]]

Comment: That's the result of my first code. Did you make sure you added the `len(l) < 4 and ` in my updated code?

Comment: Yes! The code I ran is:

    `a = [3344, 3354, 3364, 3364, 3374, 3374, 3384, 3384, 3394, 3394, 3404, 3404, 3414, 3414, 3424, 3434]

    l = []
    for i in b:
        for s in l:
            if len(l) < 4 and s[-1] + 10 == i:
                s.append(i)
                break
        else:
            l.append([i])
    print(l)`

Comment: Please see the demo here (click on the Run button): https://repl.it/repls/RadiantScarceSequences

Comment: Also, why do you have `for i in b:` when you have the list initialized as `a`?

Comment: My mistake! I was playing around with using the different lists. I clearly forgot to change it back before I pasted it into my comment. Thank you for the link, it shows that there was an error in the code posted in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` with `set` and a loop

```
b = [3384, 3404, 3344, 3394, 3374, 3414, 3354, 3404, 3384, 3424, 3364, 3414, 3394, 3364, 3434, 3374]

lst = sorted(set(b))
for i in range(4):
    print(lst[i*2:i*2+4])
```

> ```
> [3344, 3354, 3364, 3374]
> [3364, 3374, 3384, 3394]
> [3384, 3394, 3404, 3414]
> [3404, 3414, 3424, 3434]
> ```

Comment: This works out well... Would you be willing to explain what is going on in your print statement with the lst[i*2:i*2+4]?

Comment: @brandon sorry few drinks I’m me but I’ll try to explain, so basically the list begins at increments of 10 from the initial number with a double at the end of each row, if we take the set we remove the double and have a list incrementing by 10, but our output is 4 rows starting incremented by 20 so for i  in range 4 representing the 4 rows we want, we multiply i by 2 to create a 20 gap so we get 0*2 then 2, 4 , 6 And we create a list that spans 4 items for each, sorry will explain better in the morning heheh ;)